# smbpasswd failed for new Samba install on fresh Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, users, samba

I've installed Samba on a fresh Ubuntu install. I run the command

```
sudo smbpasswd -a someuser
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to add entry for user someuser.
```

I've read that you need to setup a system user, or setup a normal user for `someuser` first. I have two questions.

What is a system user?

What the correct way to setup a vanilla smb only user with either a system user, or for someuser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is a normal user account; whatever you were reading probably said "system user" to distinguish from the "samba user" you're creating now. You can create a normal user with:

```
$ useradd someuser
```

`useradd` takes miscellaneous options if you want to set things like homedir (`-d`), password (`-p`), etc. Once you've created the user account you should be able to make a new samba account. Note that giving them a regular account lets them connect to your system -- you can lock the account with:

```
$ usermod -L someuser
```

Comment: Good practice learning to use `sudo` all the time. Also `passwd -S -a` to check if the account is locked out or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just Add the User into your local login User

For Example:

```
# useradd smbuser
# smbpasswd -a smbuser
```

Then only you can able to add the user as samba user